# Clarification on Go channels tutorial from some missing word or words

Tags: go, channel

This [page](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2) on a Go Tutorial about channels seems to be missing a word(s) or was just not edited. I can't tell what it is supposed to say about sending and receiving through channels.

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready.

Is a `block` something within Go? I haven't seen it before. Is `block` being used as a noun?

I tried searching for clarification. The only other page that has similar wording is [educative.io](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-channels-in-golang)

> Moreover, by default, channels send and receive until the other side is ready

But it doesn't make sense. Do they mean:

- Channels send and receive regardless of whether or not the other side is ready? Doesn't this seem wasteful?
- Or is "**don't**" missing in the statement above?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing).   In other words, sends and receives *wait* until the other side is ready.

Comment: *Block* is a verb meaning *hinder the passage or progress of something*. See the [transitive and intransitive verb definitions
 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/block). The educative.io page appears to have been plagiarized and damaged.

Comment: Meaning that the original source was educative.io?

Comment: I know what block means in English but didn't get the technical meaning. I didn't think that `sends` and `receives` were used as nouns.

Comment: In the tutorial *sends* and *receives* are used as nouns.  Sends refers to send operations.

Comment: I meant that it looked to me like the educative.io page was hastily thrown together by someone plagiarizing other sources, hence the grammatical errors and other poor construction. But it might just be that it was written by an English-as-Second-Language speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Block" means that the goroutine will *wait.* You could write it this way:

> By default, sends and receives wait until the other side is ready.

"Block" is just the normal term for this. It is not specific to Go. It is possible to use a channel in Go in a non-blocking manner:

1. You can create a channel with a buffer. **As long as there is space in the buffer,** a write is non-blocking (but it will block if the buffer is full). **As long as there is data in the buffer,** a read is non-blocking (but it will block if the buffer is empty).
2. You can use a `select` statement with a `default` branch.

```golang
var readch chan int
var writech chan int
var value int
select {
case n := <- readch:
    // Received data.
case writech <- value:
    // Sent data.
default:
    // Didn't send or receive data.
}
```

In this code, instead of blocking (waiting), the goroutine will go to the `default` branch.